# How to block unwanted iframes to my site?

Tags: iframe

I've noticed this site : http://alexanderherr.net/ is giving me some visitors . I checked its source code and I found out there is an iframe to my old url : http://2bd4.me . Cause I redirected 2bd4.me to my new url starn.asia , When people visit alexanderherr.net , They go to starn.asia . This iframe is unwanted and I want to block it . I have no idea who did this . Can anyone help me get rid of this unwanted alexanderherr.net ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding some javascript to your page to 'break out of the frame'. Anyone visiting the site with the frame will then get sent directly to your site, without even seeing the original site, the owners of which would then probably remove the frame as it breaks their site. A quick web search brings up the following useful site (might not work with all browsers) :

http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/framebreak.shtml